# Method for checking for letter in word (Hangman code)

Tags: java

The assignment is several methods put together for the Evil Hangman code. This specific method assignment is :

Goes through the word and return an array containing the char code at the position of letter in the word, 0 otherwise.

Parameters:

theWord - the word the program picked

letter - the letter the user entered

guess - the letters guessed so far

Returns:
an array of ints, if the user correctly guessed a letter in theWord, then the char code is inserted at that position.

```
public static int[] checkLetterInWord(java.lang.String theWord, char letter, int[] guess) {
    int [] position = new int [guess.length];
    int correctGuesses=0;
    int incorrectGuesses=0;
    for (int i=0; i<position.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<theWord.length(); j++) {
        if (theWord.charAt(j)==letter) {
            position[i]=j;
            correctGuesses++;
        }
        else if(theWord.charAt(j)!=letter) {
            position[i]=0;
            incorrectGuesses++;
        }
```

I'm not sure if the method I have would work because I can't check until I have the entire class finished. If anyone could let me know if there is anything wrong with it I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using Lists

```
public static java.util.List<Integer> checkLetterInWord(final java.lang.String theWord, final char letter) {
    final java.util.List<Integer> returned = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (theWord != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++) {
            if (theWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
                returned.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return returned;
}
```

Using array

```
public static int[] checkLetterInWord(final java.lang.String theWord, final char letter) {
    if (theWord != null) {
        final int returned[] = new int[theWord.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++) {
            if (theWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
                returned[i] = i;
            } else {
                returned[i] = -1;
            }
        }
        return returned;
    }
    return new int[0];
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any other way to do it? We haven't learned lists in my CS class so I don't think I can use them.

Comment: Ok. see the edited answer. do not use zero, use -1. because zero is a valid index